# When Updating, Throw Exception if MongoDB Document Doesn't Exist

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have this class/document:

```
public class Band
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Musician> Members { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I'm updating a member within a band (Geddy's instrument and last name):

```
var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("Name", "Rushx"), Query.EQ("Members.FirstName", "Geddy"));
var update = Update.Set("Members.$.Instrument", "Vocals").Set("Members.$.LastName", "Lee");
var collection = MongoDbHelper.Db.GetCollection<Band>("Bands");
var result = collection.Update(query, update);
```

Notice that I misspelled Rush (Rushx) on purpose. We have a need to throw an exception if the root document doesn't exist. Is that possible? I know I can check this:

```
Console.WriteLine(result.DocumentsAffected);
```

However, that could fail because the musician/member doesn't exist, which we don't want to cause an exception. We could check for the root document, in a separate call first, but that's not atomic. Between that check and the update, items in the DB could change.

So... is there a way to know if the root document exists *while* doing an update so that an exception can be thrown if it's missing?

Comment: I know this adds no value to the question at all but I had to: +1 for Rush/Geddy Lee

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#findandmodify-method).

It is an atomic command, and it can return the operation result. But keep in mind that it only updates one document.

Comment: That doesn't work because `result.ModifiedDocument` is null if the band exists but the member doesn't. I have no way to know if the failure is due to the band not being there or the member not being there.